# Python - Cannot connect Python to pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo, tweepy

**I am using Python 3.5.1 this is errors:**

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KORKUSUZ\Desktop\twitter-realtime-heatmap-master\tstream.py", line 55, in <module>
    streamer.filter(track = setTerms)
  File "C:\Users\KORKUSUZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.5.egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 447, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "C:\Users\KORKUSUZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.5.egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 361, in _start
    self._run()
  File "C:\Users\KORKUSUZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.5.egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 294, in _run
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\KORKUSUZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.5.egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 263, in _run
    self._read_loop(resp)
  File "C:\Users\KORKUSUZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.5.egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 324, in _read_loop
    self._data(next_status_obj)
  File "C:\Users\KORKUSUZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.5.egg\tweepy\streaming.py", line 297, in _data
    if self.listener.on_data(data) is False:
  File "C:\Users\KORKUSUZ\Desktop\twitter-realtime-heatmap-master\tstream.py", line 48, in on_data
    col.insert(json.loads(data))
  File "C:\Users\KORKUSUZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymongo-3.2.2-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\pymongo\collection.py", line 2203, in insert
    with self._socket_for_writes() as sock_info:
  File "C:\Users\KORKUSUZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\KORKUSUZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymongo-3.2.2-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 716, in _get_socket
    server = self._get_topology().select_server(selector)
  File "C:\Users\KORKUSUZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymongo-3.2.2-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\pymongo\topology.py", line 142, in select_server
    address))
  File "C:\Users\KORKUSUZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymongo-3.2.2-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\pymongo\topology.py", line 118, in select_servers
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] Failed to connect to the target machine actively refused because
```

---

Answer (score 0):

### ## This is my Code ##

```
import tweepy
import json
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import Stream

from bson import json_util
from tweepy.utils import import_simplejson

try:
    from pymongo.connection import Connection
except ImportError as e:
    from pymongo import MongoClient as Connection

json = import_simplejson()
mongocon = Connection()

db = mongocon.tstream
col = db.tweets_tail


consumer_key="FfRhUzvXKlnS9sDWfGZqxECzQ"
consumer_secret="uhuiApn3IyzXWw34kvl8ia1DzgAaPyk2xuxXG3HtZgEIbFrWSx"

access_token="185166166-o4xUFWdjoL84K1MscTot4SfH9DZnkG5maYbhZZ6Z"
access_token_secret="2vrydY3ogq5vU8Mkqp3CAqeMmlDuRStU6iSDgNbPxDkdS"


auth1 = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth1.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    mongocon = Connection()
    db = mongocon.tstream
    col = db.tweets
    json = import_simplejson()


    def on_status(self, tweet):
        print ('Ran on_status')

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        return False

    def on_data(self, data):
        if data[0].isdigit():
            pass
        else:
            col.insert(json.loads(data))
            print(json.loads(data))


l = StreamListener()
streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth1, listener=l)
setTerms = ["bigdata", "devops", "hadoop", "twitter"]
streamer.filter(track = setTerms)
```